# Como centrar a minha localização ao clicar num marker?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

Oi!

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação que trabalha sobre o Google Maps API v2 e já defini o método `mMap.setMyLocationEnabed(true)` para obter a localização do usuário.

Minha pergunta é: como faço para, ao clicar nesse ponto azul que aparece, centrar o mapa?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904505/how-to-get-center-of-map-for-v2-android-maps
aqui explica, um cara teve a mesma duvida que você.

Comment: Isso define o centro do mapa, mas isso eu já tinha configurado. Já tinha configurado o centro do mapa para aparecer somente um país. Mas não há maneira de ao clicar no ponto azul fazer automaticamente o zoom? para o usuário não ter que fazer o zoom por ele próprio?

Answer (score 1):

Segue:

```
LatLng isMe = new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), map.getMyLocation().getLongitude());

    final CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition(isMe, ZOOM_APROXIMADO, map.getCameraPosition().tilt, map.getCameraPosition().bearing);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Cordiais Saudações,

*Correção conforme comentário:* 
Para manter o padrão, da forma que voce fez :

```
LatLng isMe = new LatLng(mGoogleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mGoogleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());  
    CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(isMe).zoom(5).build();  
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
```

Vamos muda apenas a posição fixa, para a sua Posição no Mapa (o Ponto azul).

Comment: Falha ao lançar a app... Onde tem "ZOOM_APROXIMADO" devo alterar por um valor, por exemplo 5? E acho que a variável "map" deve ser a mesma que a "mMap"...

Comment: Exato! E ZOOM_APROXIMADO e um valor númerico. Troque para 13, por exemplo

Comment: Eu tinha assim e a app era executada e mostrava o mapa... `LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(40.4830101,-4.0875573);           

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                      .target(currentLatLng)
                      .zoom(5)
                      .build();
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));` Depois da sua sua sugestão deu o erro no logcat: " Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza" Sabe o motivo?

Comment: Qual a targetSdkVersion da sua aplicação ??  Se for menor que 19 pode ser este o problema!

Comment: Editei a resposta, para manter o padrão de que vc já havia feito!

Comment: Agora dá um erro Fatal Exception: Main **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locaisproximos/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locaisproximos.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MyLocation layer not enabled**  O meu celular tem API 16, eu já alterei no AndroidManifest.xml o targetSdkVersion para 19. Qual será o erro agora?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28793/discussion-between-dan-ad-and-thiago-luiz-domacoski).